# Order By ID With String and Word Combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer table, and within id(primary key) it has a combination with 'customer'+sequential_number,

Let's say I have this data:

```
customer9998  | name1 | birtdate1
customer9999  | name2 | birtdate2
customer10000 | name3 | birtdate3
customer10001 | name4 | birtdate4
```

When I use this query:

```
select max(cust_id) from customer_table;
```

I get customer9999, which is incorrect - any suggestion how to do this, especially in sql query standard?

Comment: Frankly said: Your table structure is sh** ... You should use just an integer as `id`. It's much easier to handle and searches are faster. And you don't loose any information, right?

Comment: before you said that .. could you give me an reference of the easier one if this kind of id is shit because not using integer? how about surrogate key? is this another shit because it's not an integer?

Comment: If you had just an integer key. you could simply do `ORDER BY id`. No problems. Also it would be faster 'cause it's just about 4 bytes and not 1 byte per character (at least with utf8). ... If you mean a surrogate key to distinguish between 2 sorts of customers like `sortACustomer13` and `sortBCustomer15`, it would be far much better to use two columns: `id` (integer) and `type` varchar. Or even better to use an ENUM instead of varchar if possible. Or a second table which contains the types and then use a foreign key. It's always better to have a composite key than a string like you have.

Comment: i cannot understand what you talking about since i don't natively using english .. but i'll note this for my future reading ..

Comment: It's not my native language, too ;-). What I meant: If it's possible to use a normal integer as primary key, do it!! If you have to save two information as primary key (for example 'type_of_person' and 'number') than you can of course do it in a single column like saving `good_customer12` and `bad_customer13`, but that's bad for multiple reasons. Instead use two columns for that. One for `number` and one for `type_of_person`. you can tell your database that both columns together(!) are the primary key.

Comment: i got the point, but for me it's painful using composite key because i never use this before .. i'll leave any non-integer key in the future because it give me problem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the prefix is always the same length, then you can use:

```
order by length(cust_id) desc, cust_id desc
```

This isn't quite standard SQL, because some databases use `len()` instead of `length()`.  String functions tend to vary among databases, so I'm not sure if there is a purely database compatible way of doing this (`replace` might be common among databases).

Comment: i use this for know because it more readable to understand since i test the others

Comment: This solution is very resource consuming. Or you can make a composite FB index on (length(cust_id), cust_id)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to sort by the number of customerid field?  Assuming so, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `CAST`:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(YourField, '[^0-9]+', '') as Number))
FROM TableName
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/406c7/2)

And here's a Demo returning the field as well: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/406c7/6

Comment: hei .. this code work like a charm .. but how faster this code comparing to my accepted answer from Gordon Linoff ?

Comment: @kreamik -- Gordon's answer would be faster, assuming that's what you're looking for.  It only works assuming the prefix (the word customer in this case) is always the same length -- see this for example where it wouldn't work: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6afb/1 -- glad we could help!

Comment: ok, i'll user gordon answer and again thanks for your expalaination

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the maximum of the numbers not the strings; so you have to split the string first. The correct answer would be:

```
SELECT 'customer' || MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(CUST_ID, 9) AS NUMBER)) from CUSTOMER_TABLE;
```

`SUBSTR(CUST_ID, 9)` extracts the number (which is a string now).

`CAST(... AS NUMBER)` converts the string to number value.

`MAX(...)` selects the maximum amount.

`customer' || ...`  adds the `'customer'` immediately before this maximum value to convert it back to its original form.

Please note when you compare two numbers in string format, the result could be different from the time you compare the same numbers in numeric format. For example, between `'9'` and `'1000000000000'`, the maximum amount would be `'9'` not `'1000000000000'`. This is because the operation gets the maximum of the two strings not the two numbers. So, you'll need to convert the ID string to its equivalent number format before getting the maximum.

Comment: very explainable .. i have tested this similar way like sgeddes suggest. it work perfectly like what i need.

Comment: @Reza I'm sorry - didn't catch your solution. In fact my is the same except FBI for speeding.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() from customer_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree - your database design is not perfect :)
But you can make some workaround with queries like this

```
select max(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_id, 9))) from customer_table;
```

and a function-based index for speeding-up them

```
create index ndxCustomerNumber on customer(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_id, 9)));
```

Comment: what if i only use it as primary key, should i use it as index?

Comment: For using function SUBSTR that cut inner part from field cust_id. An ordinary index couldn't be used. Did you try my solution and benchmark it? :)